# AWS Glue Lower Case Columns

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm doing ETL from Postgres to Redshift with AWS Glue. I have imported a table with a Crawler and created a Job to just transfer the data and create a new table in Redshift. I get:

`An error occurred while calling o65.getDynamicFrame. ERROR: column "id" does not exist`

In the original table the column is "Id", case sensitive. Is there a way to make Glue case sensitive? (I don't have permissions to change the postgres schema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dyf.apply_mapping(mappings, case_sensitive = True, transformation_ctx = "tfx")
```

In mappings, you should map Id to id.

Comment: That does work as a work-around thanks. However I was hoping that the Glue GUI could setup the script without me having to edit the columns. I have 400 case-sensitive columns that I would have to edit. Any thoughts?

Comment: To be honest, it is postgresql issue. Most of db standards while naming/using columns are to keep them in lower-case automatically. However in postgresql, columns are case sensitive.